# Google Maps: Repeat GroundOverlay images along x-axis when scrolling

Tags: google-maps, kml

Is there a way to create seameless scrolling of a .kml layer that uses a GroundOverlay image? Currently I have a kml file with these properties:

```
<name>Real-Time</name>
<Icon>
    <href>http://tropicalwx.us/kml/output.png</href>
    <viewBoundScale>0.75</viewBoundScale>
</Icon>
<LatLonBox>
    <north>89.99</north>
    <south>-89.99</south>
    <east>179.99</east>
    <west>-179.99</west>
</LatLonBox>
```

However, when I move past 180 east or -180 west, the image is not repeated (see image below). Since my image is a full global stiched image, how can I make it seamless on both sides?

[image: https://i.imgur.com/avvMOk9.png]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to this question was, you can't. It's not possible with the Google maps API. The answer was using my own map server with Leaflet javascript for those wondering for the (very long) solution.